# How to access a function wihtin another function when added as property?

Tags: javascript

I need to call function b from c. I am using the following code and I receive an error.
Could you tell me what is wrong here?

```js
var a = function() {
  this.b = function() {
    alert('b');
  };
};

var c = function() {
  a.b();
};

c();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an instance of a with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```js
var a = function() {
    this.b = function() {
        alert('b');
    };
};

var c = new a;

c.b();
```

Another way is to add a property to the function and call it without a new instance.

```js
var a = function() {};

a.b = function() {
    alert('b');
};

var c = function() {
    a.b();
};

c();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `b` is not visible on the `a` which you used. To access it, you need to create an object of `a`, because you add the `b` to the `this`. It means that it will be visible on the `object` of the type `a`.

```js
var a = function() {
  this.b = function() {
    alert('b');
  };
};

var c = function() {
  new a().b(); // on the object
};

c();
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to have `b` as prototype function instead of having it inside constructor, because each time you create a new object of `a`, new function instance of `b` will be created. With prototype only one function instance will be maintained across all object instances of `a`.

```
var a = function() {
};

a.prototype.b = function() {
    alert('b');
};
```

Now you can access `b` by creating new instance of `a`

```
(new a()).b();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check how the `this` keyword works in javascript. In your code, `this` in the `a`function is bounded to the global object --which is `window` in browsers, so:

```
  var a = function() {
  this.b = function() {
    alert('b');
    };
 };
 a();
 window.b(); //will do the alert
```

As other answers state, is possible to do what your trying to do just by creating an object with the `a`function, either with:

```
var a = function() {

  return {
      b : function(){
          alert('b');
      }
  }

};
a().b(); //alert
```

Or with the `new` keyword:

```
    var a = function() {

  this.b = function() {
    alert('b');
  };
};
var obj = new a();

obj.b();
```

However, is worth mention that you don't need to explicitly create an object to achieve this behavior. You can also set a `b`member, which is a function, bounded to the `a` function:

```
var a = function() {
    //some code
};


a.b = function() {
    alert('b');
};

a.b();//alert
```

Which is more the thing you were trying to do in your question. You can do this due to the fact that functions in javascript are *executable objects* --However, to return explicitly an object and use is better than attach members to functions, imho.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate more why a function is bounded to the global object?

Comment: @Radex it is ust the way the language works: when you invoke a function from an object, `this` is bounded to that object. If you invoke a function out of nothing, it is bounded to `global` under the hood. I guess you just can't invoke bare functions, you must invoke them from an object, and the compiler does the work for you and bound bare function calls to `global`, just like `function()` declarations are bounded to vars by the compiler. It's a well known javascript 'bug': you can take a good read on this in the 'javascript: the good parts' book and in the 'you dont know javascript' series.

Answer (score 0):

Your original function is a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function), so you need to use the 'new' keyword to create an instance before calling its member function, b.

```js
var A = function() {
  this.b = function() {
    alert('b');
  };
};

var c = function() {
  var _ = new A();
  _.b();
};

c();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = function() {
           this.b = function() {
           alert('b');
           };
           return this;
        };
var c = function() {
            a().b();
        };

c();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!